# Unable to read post from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a facebook app. Here I post on user's timeline using my application. But when I try to read the same post I am always getting following error.
**(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist**

My code to read the post is following:

```
$session = new FacebookSession($token);
$response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "//{".$postid."}"))->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$postid` contains the Post's ID, then

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/".$postid))->execute();
```

should work.